# Проблемы с кодировкой при создании PDF файла с использованием itext

Tags: java, pdf, cp1251, itext

У меня возникла проблема с использованием itext 5.
Я подключил файл шрифтов для отображения кириллицы:

```
String absolutePath = context.getRealPath("") + "WEB-INF\\arial.ttf";
Font headerFont = FontFactory.getFont(absolutePath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 14);
```

Если я прямо в коде передаю в метод строку с текстом то все в порядке, текст отображается нормально:

```
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Заявление", headerFont);
```

Но я использую файл настроек `properties` и если я передаю в `Paragraph` переменную из файла `properties` то у меня уже отображаются крякозябры, по умолчанию файл `properties` имеет кодировку win1251, как я понял то PDF для отображения кириллицы тоже использует такую же кодировку, но почему у меня не работает?

```
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(bundle.getString("pdf.main.header"), headerFont);
```

Когда я получаю строку из файла `properties` c помощью getString() то мне возвращается строка в формате UTF-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому нужно, то я решил данную проблему следующим образом:
`new String(bundle.getString("pdf.signature.text").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "CP1251")`
Перекодирую строку из `ISO-8859-1` в `CP1251`, так как посоветовал `@Igor Kudryashov`

Comment: new String(bundle.getString("pdf.signature.text").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "CP1251") Что за bundle?

Answer (score 3):

properties файлы в Java по умолчанию читаются в кодировке ISO 8859-1 (см. [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)). Вам необходимо предпринимать какие-то меры по конвертации содержимого properties при чтении, а лучше сохранять файлы в соответствующей кодировке (см.[native2ascii](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html)). Как вариант попробуйте properties в формате XML.